# How to pass https requests to http in nginx

Tags: nginx, https, http, node.js, springboot

I have a self signed certificate, I deployed my front end react app on nginx which is served by using HTTPS but front end is making call to back-end spring-boot app over HTTP and when i check inspect element in browser it is showing Mixed_Block.
Please assist how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: You can redirect all http traffic to https like this: https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx